# issue with factory_girl ,devise, rpsec 2.0 and rails 3.0 => can't get rspec to validate a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rspec2

there is some ressource on github [How To: Test (devise) with Rails 3 and RSpec](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Test-with-Rails-3-and-RSpec) .
but the how to is very high level and I can't have it working in my context.
What is the proper way to plug or configure all those pieces together to managed to test a controller that require a logged user (before_filter :authenticate_user!) ???

For now I try to run rspec on a single controller..

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'
describe ArticlesController do
  fixtures :all
  render_views

  before (:each) do
    @user = Factory.create(:user)
    sign_in @user
  end

  it "index action should render index template" do
    get :index
    response.should render_template(:index)
  end
end
```

here is the output when I run rspec

```
Failures:
  1) ArticlesController index action should render index template
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     SQLite3::ConstraintException: articles.user_id may not be NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an error in your fixtures. The error message is saying that it can't create an Article without a user_id.

You can either fix the fixtures, or avoid using them by removing the `fixtures :all` and stubbing the find method:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = Factory.create(:user)
  sign_in @user
  Article.stub(:find).and_return([])
end
```

This tells `find` to return an empty array, which your controller index action should assign to the @articles instance variable for use in the template. That ought to be enough to get the template rendered without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the fixture or should say the factory this way:

```
Factory.define :article do |e|
  e.name "Article001"
  e.user { |u| u.association(:user) }
end
```

that give me this new error...

```
Failures:
  1) ArticlesController index action should render index template
     Failure/Error: response.should render_template(:index)
     expecting <"index"> but rendering with <"devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions">.
     Expected block to return true value.
```

I just want to see my test the index method of my Article controller to pass. I that point I'm not interested by the user creation. And the error is telling me that a user has been created.

I tried your proposal but get stop with "stub"

```
Failure/Error: Asset.stub(:find).and_return([])
     undefined method `stub' for #<Class:0x000000048310b8>
```

What is the best approach between `fixture:all` and your method?